# OpenID Connect protected API for a desktop application

Tags: .net, native, openid, openid-connect

I'm building a WPF .NET windows application that will connect up to an API. Because we have other APIs, I'd like to start putting all the login logic into a single module/service that handles it in a standardized way. I am thinking OpenID Connect (OIDC) is a good protocol for this.

From what I can tell, Authorization Code flow with PKCE is the way to go here. I'd like someone to confirm for me if I'm going about this the right way. Below is the flow I imagine I'll need to implement:

1. User starts the application and logs into our OIDC provider via an embedded browser (going through the Code with PKCE flow). The client is our native app and the scope is limited to 'profile' 'the-api'.
2. After the user logs in, the refresh token and access token are returned using a POST redirect that the application can intercept.
3. The native application uses that access token to get user info and display profile information in the app.
4. The native app sends a request to the API with the access_token.
5. The api verifies the user by checking the access_token at the userinfo endpoint of the OP and ensuring it has the proper scope.

I think the native client should check the access_token before sending each request to the API. If the access_token is expired or about to expire (maybe in < 30 seconds), then go fetch a new access_token before sending the request.

The thing that makes me feel unsure about this is that there is no redirect to the API. Many of the flows redirect the user to the OP, then redirect back to the API. I guess the reason this does not have that is because it's native and doesn't directly support redirects to pages like a browser would.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am thinking OpenID Connect (OIDC) is a good protocol for this**

OIDC and OAuth 2.0 is the best choice if you want to separate user identities from your application. That mean you do not hold them in your end of application but get through for example Azure AD, ADFS or even Google. Also it is the correct choice if you prefer token based authentication and authorisation. Which mean you trust tokens issued by an authorization server (also called and identity provider or OP) which is more secure than passing username/password through basic authentication.

**Authorization Code flow with PKCE is the way to go here**

Correct. Native applications such as one you are creating, which runs on windows machine of user should use PKCE with auth. code flow.

**About the flow**

I am not sure the second step, `After the user logs in, the refresh token and access token are returned using a POST redirect that the application can intercept.` I guess you are getting tokens from authorization request ? Not sure what you meant here but what ideally must happen is you should obtain authorization code after user log in in the browser instance. Once you get that you must directly call `token` endpoint of the identity provider. You get tokens as a result of this token request. And it has PKCE completion step as well.

Also `The native application uses that access token to get user info and display profile information in the app`. For this you can use ID token which comes in token response. It contains end user information. Please check more from [protocol's explanation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken).

From API end, yes it must check validity of call against access token which comes along with API request. For this it can use user_info endpoint for first time it sees a fresh access token and then cache details. And in later calls it can use cached information to detect user information. Also, some OPs send JWT based access tokens which your API can read and detect expiration details.

**I think the native client should check the access_token before sending each request to the API.**

No.! It must be the API that should do this check. Otherwise API will blindly accept tokens which can be send by some malicious client. Implement this to API end and in case access token is not valid, send a 401 - unauthorized response.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like we are on the same page but I didn't explain a few steps in as much detail. Step 5 is where I mention the API validating and checking the access token with the OP. I just meant that the native application could see if it's about to expire and renew it rather than sending it to the API with the risk that the API will just say it's expired which seems like a waste of time. The API can't redirect a native client either because it's not using a web browser at that point.

Comment: @bzuillsmith choice is yours. Either you should rely on API to send a 401 which should trigger a re-login. At this point you can still refresh_token which you obtained through token response. I hope you are getting a refresh_token ? OR else you can do a double check. One from client's logic and another at API end. I would rather keep my client logic simple and make API more intelligent. That way you can write more clients to consume API, with less boilerplate logic at client end

Comment: Makes sense. Yes, using a refresh token. The last thing I'm confused about is who is the OIDC audience/client in this process? Currently I set it to the name of the native app, but that means the API is verifying that the access token is for the native app, and not itself, right? If another app came along and also wanted to access the API, it'd be a different client. Is this okay? does the API only care that the OP says the access_token is valid and that the scope is correct?

Comment: Client is the native app. Yes, access token is issued for native app. But if native app and API is under same domain, one can say access token is good enough for API. But if it's two separate domains, then story could be different. Anyway check token introspection endpoint response as well - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7662#section-3.3 You may need that to verify audience value if you care about different values.