# Authenticating against web api with Local (individual) accounts from .NET Desktop (WPF/WinUI3)

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am looking to develop a series of applications including web, API and Windows desktop; the web application will support local "Individual" (ASP.NET Identity) accounts (as in stored in the local database, I do not want to use Azure/Entra, nor a Windows domain) and I want to be able to have the API usage authenticated in the same way when called from the Windows application.

I have looked at various options, but all I can find (especially in the M$ documentation) is examples of the Microsoft Identity Platform using Azure/Entra as the authentication mechanism which I do not want to use.

Can anybody please point me to some examples of such an authentication technique where I can authenticate that Windows application against the web application and/or API, generating a token that can then be used to authenticate further calls to the API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585132/openid-connect-protected-api-for-a-desktop-application) first. **I also think [OpenID Connect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect) (OIDC) is a good protocol for you.**

You can simply use [Identity API endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0) otherwise.

If you want to use asp.net core identity with token end refresh token endpoint with own implementation check, This example has a complete proper implementation for web API. [Source](https://github.com/andissanayake/UnifiedApp) [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@disa2aka/token-authentication-asp-net-1e7fdfb838bb)